# Get value of one table from another

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, datagridview

I have table `tblEmployees` with columns `EmployeeID, DeptID, Fname, Lname` and table `tblDepartments` with columns `DeptID, Deptname, Description`.

I'm trying to retrieve all the records from tblEmployees using datagridview but for the second column, I want to show the value of `Deptname` instead. For example I have 2 departments, 1 = dept1 and 2 = dept2. I want the output to be the name of the department instead of the DeptID. How do I do it using asp.net c#?

Also how do I combine the `Fname` and `Lname` into just one column? Thanks.

Comment: if exceed above 2 deptname for employee

Comment: @user2971155 if you specify the select Deptname from table then you can call datafield='Deptname'

Answer (score 2):

you can use sql statement like below

```
select e.EmployeeID, e.DeptID, e.Fname, e.Lname, d.Deptname, d.Description, CONCAT(e.Fname ,' ' , e.Lname) as FullName  
from 
tblEmployees e join tblDepartments  d On d.DeptID = e.DeptID
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91f1b/4)**

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you can use simple concatenation

```
SELECT `Fname` + ' ' + `Lname` as `FullName`;
```

Comment: How do I do it using ASP.NET? `<asp:BoundField datafield="Lname" headertext="Last Name"/><asp:Boundfield datafield="Fname" headertext="First Name"/>`

Comment: I'm not fmailiar with ASP.NET, does this help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1467935.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL :

```
select e.EmployeeID, e.DeptID, d.Deptname, d.Description, isnull(e.Fname,'')+' '+isnull( e.Lname,'') as empFullName from tblEmployees e join tblDepartments  d On d.DeptID = e.DeptID
```

You must need to isnull function for cancat the values otherwise if any one value is null then the concat value is also null.

For asp.net you use column name in boundfield and you need to proper name in headerfield e.g.

```
<asp:boundfield runat="server" datafield="empFullName" headertext="Employee Name" >
```